# permutation and combination problem

Tags: combinatorics

let us consider this problem:

Chelsea has a bookshelf consisting of ten classics: four Russian novels, three British novels, two French novels, and a German novel. If she wants to make sure that the novels are always grouped according to country, how many ways can she arrange the novels?

my attempt is following  because these novels  should be arranged according to country,it means that  i should multiply number of arrangement  of Russian novels together by number of British novels arrangement by French  and  one German Novels number of arrangement,which means that

$4!*3!*2!*1!=288$

but in answer there is $24*288=6912$  where  $24$ comes from?does it means that there is  $24$ ways  first book i could choose? $4*3*2*1=24$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the big group. So you have Russian, British, French, and German.
You can arrange them $4!$ ways.
For each type of book, you can arrange them $4!$, $3!$, $2!$, and $1!$ ways (which is what is in your attempt.)

So the final answer is $4!4!3!2!1!=6912$.

Comment: it means that  $4!$ is related to  number of country,not number of books right?

Comment: and also  it means that order is important right?

Comment: yes, $4!$ refers to the country, and the order matters.